# reduce number of innodb pages read by a query

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-tuning, mariadb-10.1

In my mariadb I have a large innodb table (600 millions rows). Simple queries on the table using a secondary index perform slowly so I wanted to check the number of innodb pages read to fulfill one of these queries. For that I compared the status variable *innodb_pages_read* before and after the execution of a query. In average 230 pages are read to fulfill a query that will return 200 rows.

The question is: is it normal that each query must read so much pages ? I have another similar table (but smaller with only 300 millions rows) and it takes on average only 30 pages read to fulfill a query that returns 200 rows. How could I reduce the number of pages read (and thus I/O) ?

Comment: What is `innodb_buffer_pool_size` relative to the size of each of the tables?

Comment: @DoubleT28, is taking 'innodb_pages_read' before and after query , recommended for measuring page read from disk?

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer:  It depends.

Let's start by assuming "simple query on secondary key", leads to **one row** and you have

```
INDEX(x)
SELECT * FROM t WHERE x = 123
```

Then, for 600M rows, and a *cold* cache (buffer_pool), here is the analysis:

1. Drill down the BTree for `INDEX(x)` looking for `123`:  about 5 blocks need to be read because the BTree will be about 5 levels deep.  The leaf node will give you the primary key column(s) for the one (as assumed) row with x=123.
2. Drill down the BTree for the `PRIMARY KEY` and data:  also about 5 blocks.

Total 10 blocks.

Let's expand that to saying that there are **200 rows** with x=123.

1. 5 blocks to get started in the index.
2. Scan forward in the index, perhaps 2 more blocks.  (Rule of Thumb:  100 rows per block.)
3. For each of the 200 `x=123` index entries, drill down the PK to find a row.
4. The first one (assuming cold cache) needs to read about 5 blocks (as before).
5. The other 199 will need fewer than 5 blocks.  For one thing, the root node is already there.  Are the x=123 values randomly scattered?  Or is `x`, say, a `TIMESTAMP` that marches in sync with the PK (which might be an `AUTO_INCREMENT`?)  So, these 199 could average as low as nearly 1.

Total:  ~20 to ~600.

Now let's change to **steady state**:

If your table will fit in cache, then eventually the number of blocks read will be zero.  But, let's say your 600M rows is too big for that.

Again, I invoke a Rule of Thumb:  "Ignore the drilldown, but not the leaf node".

- for 1-row:  2 blocks.
- for 200 rows:  3+200 blocks -- 3 in the index; 200 (or fewer, depending on randomness of `x` versus PK) in the data.

[*Rick's "Rules of Thumb"*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ricksrots).

**Text/Blob**

If there are large text or blob columns and you are fetching them, then "off-block" storage will be hit.  This will add perhaps at least 200 more reads -- depending of number/size/existence of the wide columns in each row.

Comment: is taking 'innodb_pages_read' before and after query , recommended for measuring page read from disk? (provided the server is restarted prior to this measurement)

Comment: @DineshKumar - It seems to be a valid way to do it.  It will also include some extra reads, such as the upper nodes in the BTree, so it is less than perfect.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** Yes, this is normal.

Remember that you're **not only** looking at **secondary** key pages read (unless it's used as a covering index), **but also at primary key page reads**. And very often it will be one or two pages read from a secondary index, resolving into page per row.

Simple example. Say you have `users` table that's clustered by `user_id` (hence it is a `primary key`). Each user has a group id set as `gid`. And you have a secondary index on that `gid`. If you query all users from a particular group, these records will likely be stored in a single secondary key page, however the `user_ids` for the matching users may well be 5, 123875, 19332234, 3343844 etc. scattered all across the primary key area.

Why and how the records are clustered by primary key in InnoDB you can read about here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html

But in a nutshell it means that innodb records are sorted on the page by primary key, but beware that page is only 16k in size (by default), so very few records fit into a single page, especially when rows are very wide.

Also to explain why you can have more pages read than rows analyzed – that has to do with the way B+Tree indexes are structured. Besides the leaf pages (where the actual data resides), there's also node pages (containing only the primary key itself) that help traverse the tree in order to find where the data resides.

Hope this explains it.